# Highcharts get series data zoom indices

Tags: highcharts

When viewing a zoomed selection of a series line graph I can query how many points are in view `chart.series[0].activePointCount` (Doesn't appear to be in API docs?). The active points are not necessarily in the zoomed view, both left/right bounds may have a single point beyond them from the active count, and I've noticed points in between the view bounds can extend beyond the top/bottom bounds.

I've received a useful answer to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196138/highcharts-dynamic-high-low-extreme-markers/) with the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/475ax4eL/) you can use for reference. It's purpose is to assign high/low marker within the current view. However `dataMax`/`dataMin` is not always correct if the point is out of bounds.

I can correct the issue comparing the `yExt.dataMax` for example with `yExt.max` and using the latter if `dataMax` is greater, this will place the marker on the top edge of the graph. I could also prevent *yAxis* zoom/scaling, and just handle the logic for the *xAxis*.

The jsFiddle method however is iterating through the entire dataset of the series. Is there a way to get the index of the first *activePoint* in the zoomed graph? Without having to iterate the entire dataset with a conditional statement. Perhaps there is an internal or undocumented variable storing the index value I'm after? Alternatively instead of a start/end index, an extracted/isolated array set of the points within the zoomed view would also work.

Comment: You have access to proceedXData / proceedYData which keeps current points, but index of this point is not set in the serie option.

Comment: @SebastianBochan `points` is available and what I was after when combined with `cropThreshold: 0` or `dataGrouping` enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chart.series[0].points` turns out to be what I was after. With the jsFiddle example, it uses *HighCharts* where the `points` array will be identical to `data`. `cropThreshold` will crop the `points` array to those in the zoom/plot bounds when the total points of your series `data` exceeds the value of  `cropThreshold`.`cropThreshold` defaults to **300**, the example dataset is 262 points. Setting `cropThreshold` to **0** will ensure the `points` array will always be cropped.

*HighStock* with it's added `dataGrouping` feature is enabled and has a similar effect providing only the points of interest in the `points` array. If you need to disable the feature, you can use `cropThreshold` instead like with *HighCharts*.

It's also worth noting that the `dataGrouping` feature modifies the `data` array, `data` begins empty but seems to insert points into the `data` array relative to their index from the dataset when you zoom or pan(perhaps other actions). Due to this behaviour your `data` array can have points stored but not starting from an index of **0**. The jsFiddle example iterates through `data` from *0 to length-1* with jQuery each(), which errors due to the initial index being greater than **0**.

It would be better to iterate the `points` array instead, which would have an added performance benefit instead of iterating through the entire dataset. It's also possible to check if a point is within the bounds by comparing against the min/max values from the x/y axis `getExtremes()` object. Excluding the out of bound points would require ignoring the dataMin/dataMax properties and iterating through `points` array comparing/storing the highest/lowest y value.

If not excluding the out of bound points, I'm not sure how to proceed yet. The provided scatter method can have the y value set to the yAxis min/max and have mouse tracking disabled to prevent the tooltip as it's y value is no longer correct, alternatively I could use a flag instead of scatter and set it's title to the actual value.